# Tinymce: How to add or modify attributes after (or during) the init phase?

Tags: tinymce

What I need basically would look something like this:

```
 tinymce.init({
     selector: '.tinymce-texteditor',
     plugins: 'code',
     height: 500,

     if (!candEdit) {
       menubar: false,
       toolbar: false,
     }     

   ...

});
```

Sure enough this code doesn't work, but the idea is to add or modify some attributes according to some external variables.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've got it. Modifications can be done into the setup method:

```
 tinymce.init({
     selector: '.tinymce-texteditor',
     plugins: 'code',
     height: 500,
     setup: function (editor) {

        ...

        if (!$('#canEdit').val()) {
            editor.settings.menubar = false;
            editor.settings.toolbar = false;
            editor.settings.readonly = 1;
        } 
      }


   ...

});
```